# How would I see if there is a transit in this light curve?

Tags: astronomy, binary-stars, exoplanets

I am trying to detect if some binary star systems have exoplanets orbiting them. I've been completing this project for many weeks now, and have managed to write some code that will plot light curves of specific TESS targets, however, I am unsure of how to proceed from here. These light curves are a lot different from those that just target a single star, and transits are a lot more difficult to detect. I am also learning python as I go through this project, so I am unsure as to how I would write code that would tell me if there is a transit on this light curve. I tried fitting a parabola but this ended up not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example light curve]

Comment: What identifies this as the light curve of a binary system? It looks like the light curve of a fast-rotating spotted star with a couple of major spot groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Identify the period of the binary. Then fold your data onto itself with the period of the binary. This way you will get one average *template* of the pure binary transit curve, where any oddities (such as transits) will be smoothed out. Now you can go and look for deviations of each given period from that template light curve. Do that either manually/visually if you just have a few periods, or automatically, by fitting each period's light curve to the template light curve, and then checking for the goodness-of-fit (e.g. the chi^2).